# Finding constant for lower bound of operator norm

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Given the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and the norms

$$\lVert A\rVert_{E} = (a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$\lVert A\rVert_{op} = \sup_{\lVert\mathbf{v}\rVert_{2}=1}\lVert A\mathbf{v}\rVert_{2}$$

I want to find a positive constant $C$ so that

$$\lVert A\rVert_{op} \geq C\lVert A\rVert_{E}$$

**What I have tried:**. Letting $\mathbf{v}=(v_{1},v_{2})^{T}$ gives me
$$\lVert A\rVert_{op} = \sup_{\lVert\mathbf{v}\rVert_{2}=1} \sqrt{v_{1}^{2}(a^{2}+c^{2}) + v_{2}^{2}(b^{2}+d^{2}) + 2v_{1}v_{2}(ab+cd)}$$

For the upper bound I was able to use AM-GM. However, I'm not sure what inequalities I need to get the lower bound. In particular, what inequality do I need to get rid of the $(ab+cd)$ term? I am not sure whether taking negatives of the AM-GM works because I can't be sure whether the overall expression under the square root is still positive. I have also tried using the equality of $p-norms$ and using the infinity norm gave me 
$$\lVert A\rVert_{op} \geq \sup_{\lVert\mathbf{v}\rVert_{\infty}=1} \max\{|av_{1}+bv_{2}|, |cv_{1}+dv_{2}|\}$$
but again, not sure how to relate this to $(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$. (I tried triangle inequality but it gave me inequality in the wrong direction).

**Bottom Line:** How can I get rid of the $2v_{1}v_{2}(ab+cd)$ term to achieve the desired inequality and find the constant? 
Note: I am not allowed to use the theorem that says any two norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take $C=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Your $\|\cdot\|_{op}$ is just the induced $2$-norm, i.e. the largest singular value of a matrix, while your $\|\cdot\|_E$ is just the Frobenius norm of a matrix. Both norms are unitarily invariant. Therefore, by singular value decomposition, if $\sigma_1\ge\sigma_2$ are the two singular values of a $2\times2$ matrix $A$, then
$$
\|A\|_{op}=\sigma_1\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\|A\|_E.
$$
In general, if the matrix is $n\times n$, you may take $C=1/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the fact that the operator norm is the largest singular value - what about a case where $\lVert A\mathbf{v}\rVert_{2}$ is maximum when $\mathbf{v}$ is not an eigenvector? Why is this still true?

Comment: @BaroqueFreak The maximum in general is attained not by an eigenvector of $A$, but by an eigenvector of $A^\ast A$. Remember that we are maximising $\|Av\|_2$. When $v$ is a unit vector, $\|Av\|_2^2=v^\ast A^\ast Av$. If you unitarily diagonalise $A^\ast A$ as $U^\ast \Sigma U$, then $w=Uv$ is a unit vector and $\|Av\|_2^2=w^\ast \Sigma w=\sum_i|w_i|^2\sigma_i$ is a convex combination of the singular values $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$. So, the maximum value is $\sigma_1$.

Comment: I like this explanation - for curiosity, is there still a way to use my approach by somehow obtaining an inequality? (i.e without using singular value decomposition and sticking to more elementary algebra and inequalities.) Would Cauchy-Schwarz help in this case?

Comment: @BaroqueFreak In the real case,
\begin{aligned}
&2[\cos^2(t)(a^2+c^2)+\sin^2(t)(b^2+d^2)+2\cos(t)\sin(t)(ab+cd)]\\
&=2\cos^2(t)(a^2+c^2-b^2-d^2)+2(b^2+d^2)+2\sin(2t)(ab+cd)]\\
&=(1+\cos(2t))(a^2+c^2-b^2-d^2)+2(b^2+d^2)+2\sin(2t)(ab+cd)\\
&=\cos(2t)(a^2+c^2-b^2-d^2)+2\sin(2t)(ab+cd)+a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2.
\end{aligned}
Both $\cos(2t)(a^2+c^2-b^2-d^2)$ and $2\sin(2t)(ab+cd)$ can be made nonnegative by an appropriate $t$. Hence the maximum possible value of the expression above is $\ge a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$, and equality holds iff $a^2+c^2-b^2-d^2=ab+cd=0$, i.e. iff the matrix is orthogonal.